# Problema con drupal 8 composer install

Tags: composer, drupal

Intento instalar el composer y me tira el siguente error, la verdad no tengo idea de como solucionarlo:

- Installing drupal/core (8.8.4): Loading from cache
- Applying patches for drupal/core
  https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2869592-remove-update-warning-7.patch (2869592 - Disabled update module shouldn't produce a status report warning)
  Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2869592-remove-update-warning-7.patch

[Exception]
Cannot apply patch 2869592 - Disabled update module shouldn't produce a status report warning (https://www.drupal.org/files/is
sues/2869592-remove-update-warning-7.patch)!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo el problema está en que tienes un patch el el composer.json que no se puede aplicar, seguramente es algo que ya la comunidad resolvió y ya no es necesario